# Number of Ways of selecting a city/cities from a list of N cities

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, subset

There is a list of N cities numbered from `1 to N`.

The task is to select the number of ways the city/cities can be chosen from the list.

At least 1 city has to be selected. As the answer can be large, print the answer modulo `10^9+7`

```
Examples
Input               Output
2 (test cases)
2                   3
1                   1
```

> For test case 1: The only ways to select the cities is 1, 2 ,1 2
>   Therefore the answer is 3.
>
> For test case 2: The only way to select a city is 1 Therefore the
>   answer is 1.

I tried in the following way (C language):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
const long int REM = 1000000000+7;
int main()
{
    int t; scanf("%d",&t); while(t--) {
        long long int n; scanf("%lld",&n);
        long long int res=1;
        for(long long int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            res<<=1;
            res%=(REM);
        }
        printf("%lld\n",res-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is giving me Time Limit Exceeded. Please suggest me a better `performance algorithm`.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *number of all possible subsets* (except the empty set) which `2^n - 1`.

As `2^n` will be very large and that's why the problem asks to do modular operation, you have to perform [Modular Exponentiation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/) to calculate `2^n`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define MOD 1000000007

// calculate (b^e) % MOD
long long powerMod(long long b, long long e)
{
    long long ret = 1;
    b %= MOD;
    while(e > 0)
    {
        if(e & 1) {
            ret = (ret * b) % MOD;
        }
        b = (b * b) % MOD;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return ret % MOD;
}


int main()
{
    long long tcase, n;
    scanf("%lld",&tcase);
    while(tcase--)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        long long result = powerMod(2, n) - 1;
        printf("%lld\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the binary exponentiation algorithm to solve each test case in logarithmic time.